# Subject Alternate Name is null when using TLS endpoint validation

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate

### Context

I'm attempting to create an SSLEngine that will validate that the subject alternate name is correct for the certificate returned by the server. I understand that java does not do this automatically and must be asked to do this. I've set up  my SSLEngine as follows

```
     //this keystore will provide client certificates, an optional part of TLS to identify the client.
     KeyStore personalKS = KeyStore.getInstance( "Windows-MY" ); //$NON-NLS-1$
     personalKS.load( null, null );

     KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance( KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm() );

     keyManagerFactory.init(  personalKS, null );
     SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance( "TLSv1.3" );

     SSLParameters sslParams = new SSLParameters();
     sslParams.setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm("HTTPS");
     context.init( keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), null, null );

     SSLEngine sslEngine = context.createSSLEngine();
     sslEngine.setSSLParameters( sslParams );

     return sslEngine;
```

Without the line `sslParams.setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm("HTTPS");` the connection succeeds for any valid signed certificate (even if its subject alternate name is incorrect).

However once I add that line I get an exception

```
com.mirada.data.dicom.network.base.AssociationFailedException: Failed to connect
    at com.mirada.data.dicom.network.ServerAssociationConnector.waitForImpl(ServerAssociationConnector.java:328)
    at com.mirada.data.dicom.network.ServerAssociationConnector.waitFor(ServerAssociationConnector.java:183)
    at com.mirada.fusionxd.export.configuration.DicomConfigurationPage$ScpDialog$4.actionPerformed(DicomConfigurationPage.java:701)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6632)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6397)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5008)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1070)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1716)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1663)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1031)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
    at com.mirada.fusionxd.export.configuration.DicomConfigurationPage$4.actionPerformed(DicomConfigurationPage.java:319)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:369)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:349)
    at com.mirada.fusionxd.export.configuration.DicomConfigurationPage$1.mouseClicked(DicomConfigurationPage.java:248)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:278)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6635)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6397)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5008)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4556)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1070)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1716)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1663)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1031)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
    at com.mirada.platform.core.ui.dialog.DialogUi.show(DialogUi.java:104)
    at com.mirada.platform.core.ui.dialog.StandardDialog.show(StandardDialog.java:171)
    at com.mirada.platform.core.ui.configuration.ConfigurationPageDialog.show(ConfigurationPageDialog.java:227)
    at com.mirada.fusionxd.application.action.PreferencesDialogAction.actionPerformed(PreferencesDialogAction.java:51)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:369)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1020)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1064)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6632)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6397)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5008)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:531)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:512)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:83)
    at com.mirada.data.dicom.network.AssociationEventHandler.get(AssociationEventHandler.java:104)
    at com.mirada.data.dicom.network.AssociationEventHandler.get(AssociationEventHandler.java:1)
    at com.mirada.data.dicom.network.ServerAssociationConnector.waitForImpl(ServerAssociationConnector.java:315)
    ... 131 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException
    at com.mirada.data.dicom.network.base.StateMachine.threadEntry(StateMachine.java:655)
    at com.mirada.data.dicom.network.base.StateMachine.lambda$0(StateMachine.java:187)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/sun.net.util.IPAddressUtil.textToNumericFormatV4(IPAddressUtil.java:49)
    at java.base/sun.net.util.IPAddressUtil.isIPv4LiteralAddress(IPAddressUtil.java:241)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.isIpAddress(HostnameChecker.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:95)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:459)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:434)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:291)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1307)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1204)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1151)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1065)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1052)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:999)
    at com.mirada.data.dicom.network.base.StateMachine.readFromSocket(StateMachine.java:839)
    at com.mirada.data.dicom.network.base.StateMachine.readNext(StateMachine.java:747)
    at com.mirada.data.dicom.network.base.StateMachine.threadEntry(StateMachine.java:582)
    ... 5 more
```

Interestingly, debugging whats going on within HostNameChecker#match shows that the X509Certificate doesn't have any subject alternate names. But the toString representation of it does.

[image]

These are internal network certificates created by me, signed by a local root CA, so its very possibly I've created the certificates wrong

### Question

How should I be setting up an sslEngine to validate the domain name as well as the certificate validation? Why am I getting this null pointer exception?

Comment: Might be understanding this slightly more. I think the X509Certificate member subjectAlternativeNames is just a cache, so its null because its not been asked for. So its a red herring and the weird thing is that expectedName is null

Comment: Seems like `context.createSSLEngine();` implicitly creates the environment with a null hostnme. And I think I need `context.createSSLEngine(hostName, port);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem was that in hostname checker the "expected name" was to be supplied by me, not as I had imagined based on the URL I was connecting to.

The correct way for me to create the SSL engine was as follows

```
SSLEngine sslEngine = context.createSSLEngine(hostname, port);
```

It is up to my code to know what host and port I expect to be communicating with (which luckily I do in my case)